# Recursive deserialization of the element from the list in XAML document using C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, serialization

How to deserialize element from the list in XAML document using C#?

I use list `Settings` to save objects of types `SettingClassA` and `SettingClassB`. Both classes have a base class `SettingClass`.

```
namespace XMLTest
{
    [Serializable]
    public class FHConfig
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = "Configuration";
        List<SettingClass> settings = null;
        public List<SettingClass> Settings { get { return settings; } set { settings = value; } }
        public FHConfig() {
            settings = new List<SettingClass>();
            settings.Add(new SettingClassA());
            settings.Add(new SettingClassB());
        }
    }
    [Serializable]
    public class SettingClass
    {
        public string SettingName { get; set; } = "Setting 1";
        public SettingClass(){}
    }
    [Serializable]
    public class SettingClassA : SettingClass
    {
        public string SettingName { get; set; } = "Setting A";
        public SettingClassA() { }
    }
    [Serializable]
    public class SettingClassB : SettingClass
    {
        public string SettingName { get; set; } = "Setting B";
        public SettingClassB() { }
    }
}
```

Serialized `xaml` file is:

```
    <FHConfig
      Name="Configuration" xmlns="clr-namespace:XMLTest;assembly=XMLTest" xmlns:scg="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
      <FHConfig.Settings>
        <scg:List
          x:TypeArguments="SettingClass"
          Capacity="4">
          <SettingClassA
            SettingName="Setting A" />
          <SettingClassB
            SettingName="Setting B" />
        </scg:List>
      </FHConfig.Settings>
    </FHConfig>
```

Suppose that I want to deserialize object of class `SettingClassA` selecting it by tag in `xaml` file. This problem has been resolved for `xml` documents in this question [How to deserialize only part of an XML document in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369792/how-to-deserialize-only-part-of-an-xml-document-in-c-sharp). But using this approach in `xaml` I can only deserialize the whole `FHConfig.Settings` list using this code:

```
    var path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), file_name);
    var xconfig = XDocument.Load(path);
    List<string> xml_path = new List<string>();
    xml_path.Add("FHConfig.Settings");
    // xml_path.Add("SettingClassA"); // When I want to deserialize only one element of the list, indicating its class name it fails.
    xconfig.CreateReader();
    try
    {
        using (var xmlReader = xconfig.CreateReader())
        {
            if (xml_path != null)
            {
                string tag = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < xml_path.Count(); i++)
                {
                    tag = xml_path[i];
                    xmlReader.ReadToDescendant(tag);
                }
                var obj = XamlServices.Load(xmlReader);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception excep)
    {
        string s_obj = "";
        foreach (var s in xml_path)
            s_obj += " " + s;
        MessageBox.Show("Creating object: " + s_obj + " from xaml: " + excep.Message);
    }
```

When I try to deserialize one of the list elements, indicating its class name, it returns the next element of the list.

For example, when I try to extract the first occurrence of type `SettingClassA`, the object created is of class `SettingClassB`.

How do I deserialize particular element in the list contained in `xaml` document, knowing its class name?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why not serialize and deserialize `FHConfig` in the normal way? What does any of this have to do with XAML? I don't understand what you mean by "selecting it by tag in xaml file"; can you show code for that part?

Comment: I suspect you mean _XML_ and not _"XAML"_.  That sample isn't XAML

Comment: I read xaml document to the particular tag using `xmlReader.ReadToDescendant(tag);`. Then I try to create object from this part of document using `XamlServices.Load(xmlReader);`. The real `xaml` file I reading is very long and I use it like database, so it is preferable to read only part of it. My C# class does not contain typical XML attributes, like `[XMLRoot]`, so to save it I used `XamlServices.Save()`. It would be impossible to do using `XmlSerializer`.

Comment: Why aren’t you using a real database? If it’s too large for a flat file, it’s too large for a flat file.